# wifi and dual monitor is lost after updating nvidia driver

Tags: networking, drivers, nvidia, 22.04, multiple-monitors

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a Lenovo Legion pc with nVIDIA 4090. During installation, wifi was detected and I was able to connect to the internet. I tried to install CUDA 12.3, and after rebooting, I lost the Wi-Fi connection and only one monitor is detected now. Apparently, there is a problem with drivers. When I run lshw, I can see two unclaimed networks, which means all of the drivers are not installed properly.

As I do not have access to the internet, I am not sure how I can update drivers or fix the problem. I can attach a USB to the PC with the Ubuntu installation disk. Can I reset Ubuntu so it can install its drivers again?

## Edit 1

I could not fix the problem and was forced to re-install Ubuntu. After re-installing, my dual monitor and wifi worked well until I tried to enable hibernation and reboot the system. Now my wifi is not working.
the result of running this command:

```
sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status
```

is

```
Status: install ok installed
```

Any way that I can make the wifi to work again?

The device is Intel Co Device 7070 (as I can see from lspci)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status`

Comment: Please show us: `sudo lshw -C network`

Comment: I already did it. It shows that there is two network card, one is claimed and the other is not claimed. The claimed one is Ethernet and the unclaimed one is an Intel card which I belive is the wifi.  As I don't have access to the internet from the Linux PC, I can not copy/paste the entire output.

Comment: "The device is Intel Co Device 7070 (as I can see from lspci)" Please run: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Tell us what follows: `[8086:   ] and whether any kernel modules are listed.